# When do we flip the inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $a>b$. What properties must a function $f(x)$ have in order for $f(a)>f(b)$ to be a true? What properties must $g(x)$ have so that $g(a)<g(b)$? Does $f(x)$ have to be monotone increasing and $g(x)$ monotone decreasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case: $f$ must be strictly decreasing or, if $f$ is differentiable, it is sufficient (but not necessary) that $f'<0$.  In the second case, $g$ must be strictly increasing, or $g'>0$.

Note that $g(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing, even though $g'(0)=0$.  A complete answer for a differentiable function $g$ is: $g$ is strictly increasing if $g'\geq0$ everywhere, and the set $\{x:g'(x)=0\}$ contains no intervals.

Comment: Is what I asked then essentially the definition for strictly increasing? i.e.

If $a>b$ and $f(a)>f(b)$, then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @BenLongo, Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $a>b$ this inequality implies $f(a)>f(b)$, then you're looking for a strictly increasing function, by definition.

Similarily $a>b \implies g(a)<g(b)$ for any $a,b$ in the domain is a definition of a strictly decreasing function.